# Positioning Offset div / Images

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve this result (see this example image).

[image]

First, I’ve tried to create partial borders with CSS (using `div:after`).  Problem : I have several images with different formats and it is not working properly. So, I’ve tried with a background div with `position: relative` and an image in `position: absolute`.

Its works but it’s not easy to handle in responsive mode. I need to set a with and a height to the div which contains the image and sometime the container is too big.

```css
.container-image-border {
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: #fd9220;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
}

.container-image-border img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-image-border">

  <img alt="example" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x250">

</div>
```

Is there an other way to achieve this ?

Comment: This https://prnt.sc/pbsft6 ?

Comment: in case you want to consider some offset here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57993144/8620333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need to wrap your `<img>` elements with `<div>`: using `box-shadow` will do the trick:

```css
img {
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 0 0 #fd9220;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<img alt="example" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x250">
<img alt="example" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x150">
<img alt="example" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
```

The problem with wrapping using a `<div>` is that it is a block-level element by default, and has a width of `100%` unless otherwise specified. This makes it difficult to "shrink wrap" the element around your `<img>` element, since your image has an undetermined size.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.container-image-border {
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 0 0 #fd9220;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-image-border">

  <img alt="example" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x250">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about box shadows?

```css
img {
  background-color: grey;
  box-shadow: -30px 30px 0 0 orange;
  margin-left: 40px; /* just for the presentation */
}
```

```html
  <img alt="example" src="https://placehold.it/150x250">
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
img {
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 0 0 #fd9220;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-image-border">

  <img alt="example" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x250">

</div>
```